# Sort nested defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a nested dictionary:

```
nestedDict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
```

it has values of the form:

```
termId: {
    'docId': [position1, position2, position3, position4],
    'docId': [position1, position2, position3, position4]
}
```

eg:

```
95074715468325493716883841120098961347 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{'193083866963132215734985636049608586841': [1922, 1948, 1952, 1954], 
 '39188502589169058624219974133946618900': [1922, 1948, 1952, 1954]})
```

I want to sort it on the basis of docId in ascending order as

For Example:

```
1: {1:[1,2,3],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,3,4]} //docId should be in ascending order in each row

2: {1:[1,2,3],2:[1,3,4],3:[1,3,4]}
```

I am trying this:

```
orderedDict = OrderedDict(sorted(nestedDict.items(), key=lambda t: nestedDict[1][0]))
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to get it right. I am new to python.Sorry for asking this basic question.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: We rebuild the dictionary around an ordered inner dict.

**Given**

```
import collections as ct


nested_dict = ct.defaultdict(lambda: ct.defaultdict(list))
d = {95074715468325493716883841120098961347:
     {
        "193083866963132215734985636049608586841": [1922, 1948, 1952, 1954], 
        "39188502589169058624219974133946618900": [1921, 1948, 1952, 1954],
        "100" : [1923, 1948, 1952, 1954], 
    }
}
nested_dict.update(d)
```

**Code**

```
>>> {k: ct.OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[0]))) for k, v in nested_dict.items()}
{95074715468325493716883841120098961347: OrderedDict([
    ('100', [1923, 1948, 1952, 1954]),
    ('39188502589169058624219974133946618900', [1921, 1948, 1952, 1954]),
    ('193083866963132215734985636049608586841', [1922, 1948, 1952, 1954])])}
```

---

**Details**

The code for the `OrderedDict` sorts the inner dictionary by a key.  Note: these keys are numeric strings and are thus sorted using the `float()` builtin: Example:

```
inner_dict = {
    "200": [], 
    "300": [], 
    "100": [],    
}

ct.OrderedDict(sorted(inner_dict.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[0])))
# OrderedDict([('100', []), ('200', []), ('300', [])])
```

The remaining dictionary comprehension rebuilds the dictionary around these sorted dicts.  If you wish to maintain the outer `defaultdict` type, rebuild accordingly:

```
rebuilt_dict = ct.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in nested_dict.items():
    rebuilt_dict[k] = ct.OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[0])))

rebuilt_dict
```

Comment: .It is sorting in descending order?

Comment: @MuhammadRaghib, it wasn't clear in your question whether you wanted to sort your keys as though they're integers or strings. `int('10') >  int('3')`, but `'10' < '3'`. Remove that call to `int` if you prefer the latter.

Comment: @ymbirtt this code is sorting on the basis of keys (outer dictionary).I want to sort it on the basis of keys of inner dictionary:309767110602326329470352776628338681619 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'193083866963132215734985636049608586841': [1895], '39188502589169058624219974133946618900': [1895], '311107235584665083555814081636686808932': [197]}).It should be of form309767110602326329470352776628338681619 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'193083866963132215734985636049608586841': [1895], '311107235584665083555814081636686808932': [197] '39188502589169058624219974133946618900': [1895] )

Comment: It is more clear now what you want.  See the update.